# Java IntelliJ No such file exception even with correct JDK in place

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have tried everything i have seen. Made sure the correct JDK was installed, made sure the txt file was in the correct working directory but nothing. I keep getting the no such file exception. And this is not the only project that i am working on that is giving me this problem. I dont know what the problem is:
[image]

[image]

Comment: try with `Paths.get("src/cipher.txt"));`

Comment: Don't provide screen shots for code. Provide code as text within your post.

Answer (score 1):

When run in IDEA the following code shows that your working directory is a project directory, not the `src` one:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("CWD: " + System.getProperty("user.dir"));
    }
}
```

Which means you should do one of the following:

- refer to your file with an absolute path
- refer to you file with "src" in relative path (src/cipher.txt)
- move file one level up so that "cipher.txt" would work (relative to CWD)
- change your working directory in runtime, which might be not the best idea

PS: JDK has nothing to do with it